# Background not working on Lg G3

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an Xamarin Android app and have a background image that I use. It works great on almost all devices except LG G3. I see that it has a 1440x2560 resolution, I tried putting the background image to that resolution too in the Resources but it still doesn't show. Does anyone know which would be the right resolution that I should use ?
Thank you all for your help !